# Inputting a number and returning the product of all the even integers between 1 and that number

Tags: python, python-3.x

*I'm looking for help on the question:*

So far my code has gotten me far enough to return the right answer but also the restultant multiplication along the way, i.e.: (1, 2, 2, 8, 8, 48). Can anyone reshuffle or redo the code so it just outputs the answer only, thanks in advance!

```
counter=1
product=1

userinput=int (input ("What number: "))

for counter in range (1, userinput):
    if counter%2==0:
        product=int (counter*product)
        counter=counter+1

    else:
        counter=counter+1

    print (product)
```

Comment: If you prefer one liners `reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(2,<num + 1>, 2))`

Comment: `__import__('functools').reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(2, int(input('What number: '))+1, 2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because `print` is executed on every iteration, you need to execute it only after the loop ends, which means `print` must have the same indent level as the loop,

```
counter=1
product=1

userinput=int (input ("What number: "))

for counter in range (1, userinput):
    if counter%2==0:
        product= int(counter*product)


print(product)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the indent level of `print(product)` if you wish to print it after finishing for loop as below. And, another important thing is that you do not need to work on `counter` variable as it is incremented with `for counter in range(1,counter)`:

```
product=1

userinput=int (input ("What number: "))

for counter in range (1, userinput):
    if counter%2==0:
       product=int (counter*product);

print (product)
```

Comment: @Sufiyan Ghori, I started writing answer when there was no answer posted. After posting solution, I found that you already posted solution. But, I saw that you did not mention anything about unnecessary operations in counter variable. So, I keep it here. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just read the comments i have added to your code and the modifications.

```
product=1

userinput=int (input ("What number: "))

if userinput = 1: # add these
    return 0      # lines

for counter in range (1, userinput + 1): # add 1 here
    if counter%2==0:
        product=counter*product # here you didn't need int() at all
    # you also don't need to increment counter because it is getting incremented in the for loop

print (product) # decrement this line to the same level of "for counter ..."
```

**Edit:**
if the user gives 0 or negative numbers you can consider this code, which is cleaner overall i guess

```
def main(n):

    product = 1

    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 0

    range_step = 1
    if n < 0:
        range_step = -1

    for counter in range(1, n+range_step, range_step):
        if counter == 0:
            continue
        elif counter % 2 == 0:
            product = counter*product

    return product


if __name__ == '__main__':
    userinput = int(input("What number: "))
    product = main(userinput)
    print(product)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do **two modifications** to your code.

1.>  **Change the indentation of the last line** `print (product)`.

2.> In the `for` loop, change `userinput` to `userinput+1` (to get proper answer for inputs which are even numbers.)

Check the following code. =)

```
counter=1
product=1

userinput=int (input ("What number: "))

for counter in range (1, userinput+1): #userinput changed to userinput+1
    if counter%2==0:
        product=int (counter*product)
        counter=counter+1

    else:
        counter=counter+1

print (product) #Indentation of last line changed.
```